# How to get Grails application name within Config.groovy?

Tags: grails, configuration, configuration-files, grails-config

I want to include the Grails application name in some of my configuration settings in `grails-app/Config.groovy`.  I've tried many ways without success.  For example, if I have the following in my `Config.groovy`,

```
edu.appname1 = "${grailsApplication.metadata.'app.name'}"
edu.appname2 = "${application.metadata.'app.name'}"
edu.appname3 = "${metadata.'app.name'}"
edu.appname4 = "${app.name}"
```

I can run these statements in the Grails console

```
def edu = grailsApplication.config.edu
println "${'''${grailsApplication.metadata.'app.name'} -> '''}${edu.appname1}"
println "${'''${application.metadata.'app.name'}       -> '''}${edu.appname2}"
println "${'''${metadata.'app.name'}                   -> '''}${edu.appname3}"
println "${'''${app.name}                              -> '''}${edu.appname4}"
```

with the following results.

```
${grailsApplication.metadata.'app.name'} -> [:]
${application.metadata.'app.name'}       -> [:]
${metadata.'app.name'}                   -> [:]
${app.name}                              -> [:]
```

There must be some way to get this information.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To get the appName in a config file that you're including with `grails.config.locations` you can use:

```
appName = grails.util.Metadata.current.'app.name'
```

Comment: I am googling this statement. It works for me on grails 2.3.11. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect it is just what I need. You can also use grails.util.Metadata.current.getApplicationName() as an equivalent

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
edu.appname1 = appName
```

or if you want to use as part of a longer configuration parameter

```
edu.appname1 = "something.$appName.else"
```

Comment: My problem was that it wasn't available in a file I included via `grails.config.locations`.  I'll just save it to a new property in `Config.groovy` and use that.