# Access sub-project application properties in grails/groovy

Tags: grails

I have a singleton class

```
@Singleton
class CustomerBundleSingleton {

    def grailsApplication = Holders.getGrailsApplication()
    String projName
    private CustomerBundleSingleton() {

        line 10: projName = // how to get sub-project name here ???

    }

}
```

---

```
application.properties // my project is running
-----------------------
app.name = MyNewProject


application.properties // located in sub project
-----------------------
app.name = MySubProject
```

I tried `grailsApplication.metadata['app.name']` in `"line 10:"` it returns `"MyNewProject"`.Whereas I want a way to get the project name of the UserBundleSingleton located (MySubProjectName). Something like grailsApplication.current.metadata['app.name'] ???? .

So that it can give me back `MySubProjectName` instead of `MyNewProject`??

Comment: By "subproject" you mean a plugin?

Comment: Yes that is a plugin under the main project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809566/how-to-get-grails-application-name-within-config-groovy Try `grails.util.Metadata.current.'app.name'`.

Comment: I have grailsApplication inside my class, if i try `grailsApplication.util.Metadata.current.'app.name'` gives me "util is not a defined property".  If I use `Holders.getGrailsApplication().metadata.current.'app.name'` I am getting back cannot call `app.name` on null object

Comment: The Matadata is a class, not an attribute of grailsApplication.

Comment: @SérgioMichels yeah i tried something like this :  `Holders.getGrailsApplication().getMetadata().getCurrent().get("app.name")` it again gave me 'MyNewProject' instead of `MySubProject`

Comment: @user2001627 Metadata is a separate class. If it helps, you can do `import grails.util.Metadata` and then `def appVersion = Metadata.getCurrent().'app.version'`. I would say you don't need the grailsApplication at all.

Comment: @lucke84 I tried that too but it is still giving me `MyNewProject` not `MySubProject`

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 suggestions depending on your requirements and your 'bundling'.

**1) You don't have a bundle marker/descriptor**

Assuming that you know the sub-project(Grails plugin) name, your life gets easier, instead of having to loop through all plugins...

You can probably use something among these lines.

```
// Plugin name is 'hibernate' in this example

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.PluginManagerHolder

def hibernateVersion = PluginManagerHolder.pluginManager.getGrailsPlugin('hibernate').version

// Loop through all plugins
// PluginManagerHolder.pluginManager.getAllPlugins()
```

**2) Using custom plugin properties to lookup plugins of interest**

Other strategy, if you must lookup the bundle dynamically.

Create a custom marker property in each of your plugin descriptors

```
def specialProperty = "whatever"
```

Then inside your CustomerBundleSingleton

```
PluginManagerHolder.pluginManager.getAllPlugins().each {
     if (it.properties.specialProperty) {
               def subProjectName = it.name
               def subProjectVersion = it.version
     } 
}
```

**3) Custom bundle info resolution**

You may also want to consider some metadata  via *META-INF/MANIFEST.MF* or similar mechanism.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. To get the property app.name from application.properties inside a the sub-project isn't there any simple way to get it like grailsApplication.util.Metadata.current.'app.name'?? of course this line didnt work :( but I thought there could be simple way to get it. I am a new bee for grails/groovy.If there is no other way then i will start trying your inputs one by one.

Comment: I don't know any other way, but also don't know your exact requirements. You could do grailsApplication.util.Metadata.getInstalledPlugins (http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/util/Metadata.html#getInstalledPlugins()) -> You still need to know what to look for though...